# Trying to call PHP file using jQuery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I am developing using jQuery 2.0.2 on Debian 7.0.0.

I am trying to call a PHP script from a JavaScript file using jQuery.ajax.  My code is as follows.

```
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "DisplayParameters.php",
    data: { LUT:lut, 
        Brightness: brightness,
        Gamma: gamma,
        Background: background}
    }).done(function( result ) {
    $("#msg").html( " Ajax called" );
    });
```

At the beginning of  DisplayParameters.php, I have the following.

```
?>
<script language="JavaScript">
alert('DisplayParameters');
</script>
<?php
```

but the alert box is not called.  Firebug proceeds without any errors and shows the DisplayParameters.php text (with a +/- control to collapse and expand it).  But the alert box is not called.  I cannot get any feedback from DisplayParameters.php to trace what is happening.

What would be the best way for me to get feedback (like alert boxes or console.log) from DisplayParameters.php?

Comment: Please post the full code of `DisplayParameters.php`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ajax call returns the contents of `DisplayParameters.php` as text, `console.log(result)` would show:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
alert('DisplayParameters');
</script>
```

If you want to add this extra code to the page (which I don't recommend unless you are sure you won't break the current page), you can try:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "DisplayParameters.php",
    data: { LUT:lut, 
        Brightness: brightness,
        Gamma: gamma,
        Background: background}
}).done(function( result ){
    $("#msg").html( " Ajax called" );
    $("body").append(result);
});
```

Another approach would be to serialize (JSON) the information you need, set the `dataType: "json"` option, and act based on this information.

If you will send HTML, ensure your PHP code doesn't shows any error or warning messages.

Comment: Thanks.  I did not explain my objective very well.  I was initially hoping to get some feedback from DisplayParameters.php to see how to get feedback.  The I was hoping to get the strings that were formed from the input arguments.  I found that I could this by using echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">"; with echo "console.log('str='+" . $str . ");"; statements in the PHP file.  The results would show up in the DisplayParameters.php text (with +/- controls in Firebug.  Thanks, Peter.

Answer (score 1):

The `alert()` should happen inside `.done()` on the ajax call. Like the following:

```
.done(function(result) {
    alert(result);
    $("#msg").html( " Ajax called" );
});
```

And instead of alerting on DisplayParameters.php, use `echo` so that that will be the returned value for result. Like the following:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    //...some JS codes here
    <?php echo 'DisplayParameters'; ?>
</script>
```