# Replace iFrame with jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am using iFrame to call common footer and header into a muti-site wordpress but the header and footer load much later than the rest of the site.  Here is what I have for the footer:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" height="395px" frameborder="0" width="100%" src="http://domain.com/common-footer/" class="footer-frame"></iframe>
```

Is there a better way to do this or to improve this?  Thanks much.

Comment: Uhm, PHP comes to mind, and especially the built in methods in Wordpress for actually including headers and footers ?

Comment: Well, trying to share the main's header and footer dynamically with other sites/themes in wordpress and my developer came up with this "iFrame" solution.  Now that I see the delay in loading, I'm trying to see if it can be improved somehow.

Comment: Your developer sucks, find someone else or read the Codex yourself and learn how it should be done, this is all built in ready to go -> **http://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_into_Templates**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this easily with jQuery with the `.load()` function.  Use it like this:

```
<script> 
$(function(){
  $("#header").load("header.html"); 
  $("#footer").load("footer.html"); 
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header"></div>
<!--Remaining section-->
<div id="footer"></div>
```

For more information about the `.load()` function: http://www.jquery-tutorial.net/ajax/the-load-method/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, I'm a learner... So I will need to place the literal location of the header/footer in that script...right?  like: "http://domain.com/common-footer/"

Comment: Do you need additional help?  How can I help?  At your service.

Comment: I need to call commen-footer.php into footer of a site.  Will this work in that format you presented?

Comment: Yes, you can make it do something like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257436/trying-to-call-php-file-using-jquery-ajax